# Pycharm-like autocompletion in Vim

Tags: python, c++, vim, autocomplete

Is there a way to make "Vim's autocomplete" act like Pycharms?

I tried YouCompleteMe but it doesn't show all the possible functions and variables after the first letter typed. I find this extremely useful because I'm still a beginner.

I'm looking for the same thing for C++.
The reason I don't want to use Pycharm and Clion is hardware limitation and I really like Vim.

Can it be done somehow?

Comment: Instead of adding PyCharm's features to VIM (which might not be possible, PyCharm is a big and complex program), why not use PyCharm with [VIM keybindings](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2011/04/pycharm-your-vim/)?

Comment: A big surprise for all Vim users to find that PyCharm provides an outstanding Vim emulation! - I was definitely in this category.
This is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @JoleMile Very similar task https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/119

Answer (score 1):

I use [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) . first install it then install [deoplete-clangx](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete-clangx) for cpp and [deoplete-jedi](https://github.com/deoplete-plugins/deoplete-jedi) for python .
If you have plugin manager, add these lines to your ~/.vimrc :

```
Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim'
Plug 'Shougo/deoplete-clangx'
Plug 'deoplete-plugins/deoplete-jedi'
```

Then save file and type `:PluginInstall` for install plugins .
( if your plugin manager is [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) , you must use `Plugin` instead of `Plug` )

**Another way**

You can use [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) .